# C++ code exploit

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am learning basic buffer overflow issues, can anyone please explain how this code can be exploited.

```cpp
char gWelcome [] = "Welcome to our system! ";

void echo (int fd)
{
    int len;
    char name [64], reply [128];

    len = strlen (gWelcome);
    memcpy (reply, gWelcome, len); /* copy the welcome string to reply */

    write_to_socket (fd, "Type your name: "); /* prompt client for name */
    read (fd, name, 128);                     /* read name from socket */

    /* copy the name into the reply buffer (starting at offet len, so
     * that we won't overwrite the welcome message we copied earlier). */
    memcpy (reply+len, name, 64);

    write (fd, reply, len + 64);
    return;
}

void server (int socketfd) {
    while (1)
        echo (socketfd);
}
```

Comment: is the question "why can it be exploited?" or "Can you give me an example of how to exploit it?"

Comment: You are reading up to 128 bytes for `name`, but you have allocated only 64 for the char array.